# Does JSF cache the state of each component in between the two requests?

Tags: java, jsf

"*In JSF, the state of the each component is stored in between the requests*" -  This means that the data is cached(!?) at the application servers thus the servers will now have larger memory requirements(!?).

But I guess we can also make the state `requestScoped`, so this will not cache the data at application servers during the two requests, right? Am I getting it correctly ?

[My application contains blog posts of users which are large text blobs which would be very costly to cache. But yes *there is some data* that requires caching! ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence you mention here is about JSF state saving, which saves the state of the component tree. By default, this is done on the server... but you could also do it on the client, to save some mememory. See this: http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=JavaServerFacesRI#section-JavaServerFacesRI-WhatAreTheDifferencesBetweenServerAndClientSideStateSavingAndWhatAreTheBenefitsDrawbacksOfEach

Backing beans scope is something else. You can make backing beans session / request / view scoped (or even use another or custom scope). This will have an impact on server memory usage. However, if you do it correctly and don't have big data requirements, you could manage that. For example, you could store as little as possible and reload your data regularly (from db, ...).

All this doesn't mean your data is cached (at least, not the data coming from persistent storage). This is up to you.

So, memory requirements are something to keep in eye. The basic setup for a full-blown Java EE server is typically more than for a php application on an apache server... But, done correctly, making it faster / better / more scalable (cpu / mem) could be simpler to achieve.

Comment: So how can I make it stateless, so that the data(state) is  not stored between the requests?? Else if I leave it as it is then the data will be cached right?  I am looking to mix some data whose state will be stored and some whose state wont be stored.

Comment: I expected that if I limit the scope of backing beans to requestscoped then the state wont be stored between the two requests

Comment: If by data, you just mean "what I retrieved from the database", then it has nothing to do with JSF and caching doesn't happen there. If you put something (the data from db?) in a managed bean property, its scope will be that of the bean itself. Also, don't try to overly optimize. If you have to reload the same data on each request, consider storing that data in session (or some intermediate scope). Anyway, aren't you mixing JSF state saving (component tree) and managed bean scope?

Comment: sorry but I am still confused between JSF state data storage & backing beans storage. I believed the component state was stored in corresponding the beans themselves. Now why is the same state being stored twice(in beans as well as JSF state). Again I am sorry for I am really confused..

Comment: JSF state saving is about saving the component tree. The component tree is a structure containing the state of each component. A component can have many visible and invisible properties, which state is stored there. You can bind the value of those properties to a backing bean, but you don't have to bind them all. So, the component tree is saved somewhere (server or client), automatically. And managed bean properties are stored in the bean scope (request / session object, ...).

Answer (score 1):

In the last year I had to create two JSF applications. If I remember correctly you could cache your data in your Backing Bean so that you do not hit your database to retrieve your blog contents with every refresh.

Pretty much JSF has a very strong server-client presence. It is pratically impossible to imagine that JSF will only run on the client like GWT.

Are you using IceFaces or any other JSF implementation like RichFaces?

Comment: I am looking forward to choosing a component library right now, for a social network application.. do you have any recommendations ? I am more inclined towards primefaces & richfaces

Comment: primefaces is the oldest jsf2 lib, and has a great number of components